# How to format Laravel Link with <i> and <span> tags

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

How to format Laravel Link with `<li>` and `<span>` tags, for an example:

**Laravel Link**
{{ link_to('home', 'Home') }}

**Should have to set like this**

```
                <li>
                    <a href="home">
                        <i class="icon-text-width"></i>
                        <span class="menu-text"> Home </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

can someone please help me to create Laravel base link with that html tags, thank you

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, you can not do that using `{{ link_to('home', 'Home') }}`. However, instead you can do something like the following:

```
<li>
     <a href="{{ route('home') }}">
        <i class="icon-text-width"></i>
        <span class="menu-text"> Home </span>
     </a>
</li>
```

or you can use `url()` helper function.

```
<li>
     <a href="{{ url('/') }}">
        <i class="icon-text-width"></i>
        <span class="menu-text"> Home </span>
     </a>
</li>
```